# Adding a list of extra dependencies in YAML using hyphens in RMD file?

Tags: r, yaml, latex, rstudio

I have the following YAML given to me as an RMD template for use in a course:

```
---
title: "Chapter 1"
author: 
output:
  pdf_document:
    extra_dependencies:
    - geometry
    - multicol
    - multirow
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
---
```

However, according to https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/docs/reference/pdf_document.html, a character vector should be used for the key "extra_dependencies", so how come a hyphened list is allowed?

I don't see any documentation or explanation for this, resources explaining this are welcomed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The need for `extra_dependencies` to be a character vector is an R thing. What you have above is not R, it's YAML, which is different. If you see what R gets when it parses this header, you'll see

```r
yaml::yaml.load(string='
title: "Chapter 1"
author: 
output:
  pdf_document:
    extra_dependencies:
    - geometry
    - multicol
    - multirow
  html_document:
    df_print: paged')

# $title
# [1] "Chapter 1"
# $author
# NULL
# $output
# $output$pdf_document
# $output$pdf_document$extra_dependencies
# [1] "geometry" "multicol" "multirow"
# $output$html_document
# $output$html_document$df_print
# [1] "paged"
```

where you can see that the embedded `$output$pdf_document$extra_dependencies` is indeed a `character` vector.

---

From the current [YAML spec](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html), [section 3.1.1](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2762313) defines

> ... the sequence corresponds to a Perl array and a Python list ...

(which, to me, is analogous to R's vector), and in [section 2.1](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2759963), example 2.1 ("Sequence of Scalars") demonstrates a sequence as

```yaml
- Mark McGwire
- Sammy Sosa
- Ken Griffey
```

which means that a sequence in yaml (which is a list in python and a vector in R) is encoded as a bullet-list (optionally-indented) using hyphens for each element.

Recall that R requires a `character` vector for the `pdf_document` function. The header in R-markdown documents is not R, it's YAML, so the question is *"how to encode the options in the yaml header so that R will eventually see it as a vector of strings"*. This is how, as an indented list, using hyphens to identify each element.

Comment: so for YAML is a character list always a hyphenated like that? I couldn't find a link explaining that...

Comment: It's how R's `yaml` package is interpreting it. I think it's how YAML is defined, though I have not parsed through the entire [YAML spec](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html) to verify. If you read that (it's not short), it might be clearer. Ultimately, though, you are asking where in YAML it is defined so that parsing it will render a string vector for R's use in `pdf_document`. I don't know how to answer that without more reading ... but that is a way to get the desired format.